# Map of extended Europe with Cartopy

Tags: python, cartopy

The following Python code produces a good view of Western Europe:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.EuroPP())
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, linestyle='-', alpha=1)
ax.coastlines(resolution='10m')
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN,facecolor=(0.5,0.5,0.5))
ax.gridlines()
```

But, what would be the way to extend the map to the East, including Turkey and other Caucasian States? Do I need to include some parameters in `()` of `EuroPP()`? Do I need to change `projection=ccrs.EuroPP()` for something else? Didn't find any examples...

[image]

Comment: Look at the source [how `EuroPP` is defined](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/_modules/cartopy/crs.html#EuroPP).

Comment: Yes, I see how `class EuroPP(UTM)` is defined... and so?

Comment: I just delete my answer because it wont work as expected. It only works in low latitude areas. Sorry for that. I will try another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the map with similar projection, Transverse Mercator with central meridian at 32 degrees longitude, try running this code:

```
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(9, 9))
ax = plt.axes(projection=cartopy.crs.TransverseMercator(32))
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, linestyle='-', alpha=1)
ax.coastlines(resolution='110m')
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN, facecolor=(0.5,0.5,0.5))
ax.gridlines()
ax.set_extent ((-7.5, 50, 34, 69), cartopy.crs.PlateCarree())
plt.show()
```

You will get the plot like this:

[image: europe_map]

Comment: Well, it's very nice! Precisely what I wanted and what I couldn't do. Thank you so much.